# Using an AngularJS timeout

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I'm new to AngularJS. I'm currently looking at the $timeout service. I understand that it's like a wrapper for the setTimeout function. The documentation says that it provides exception handling. In addition, the documentation says I can cancel and flush a timeout.

Can someone please explain to me when an exception would happen with a timeout? I also don't understand why I need to flush a timeout. I would love an explanation or maybe a jsfiddle. For the life of me, I can't figure out why or even how to use these additional features.

Update:
When I attempt to run the stop function, the catch handler associated with myTimer get's thrown. Here is my code:

```
var myTimer = null; 
$scope.hasStarted = false; 
$scope.start = function () { 
  if ($scope.hasStarted === false) { 
    $scope.isTimerActive = true; 
    myTimer = $timeout(function () { $scope.isTimerActive = false; }, 5000); 
    myTimer.catch(function (err) { 
      alert("An error happened with the clock."); 
    }); 
  }
} 

$scope.stopClock = function () { 
  $timeout.cancel(myTimer); 
  $scope.isClockActive = false; 
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$timeout` is most awesome indeed.

#### Exception handling

`$timeout` returns a promise which can have an error state. For example

```
 var timePromise = $timeout(function(){ 
    throw new Error('I messed up');
 }, 10000);

 timePromise.catch(function(err){
    // do something with the error
 });
```

read all about promises [here.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q)

---

#### Cancel

Canceling a `$timeout` is easy. Instead of using `clearTimeout` you pass the promise back.

```
 var timePromise = $timeout(function(){
     // do thing
 }, 23432);

 // wait I didn't mean it!
 $timeout.cancel(timePromise);
```

---

#### Flush

Flush is most useful for unit testing, ultimately it fires any outstanding callbacks.

```
$timeout(function(){
   console.log('$timeout flush');
}, 222);

$timeout(function(){
   console.log('rocks my face');
}, 234232);

$timeout.flush(); // both console logs will fire right away!
```

or this file:

```
var itsDone = false;
$timeout(function(){
   itsDone = true;
}, 5000);
```

with this test:

```
// old no flush way (async)
it('should be done', function(done){
   expect(isDone).to.be.false;
   setTimeout(function(){
      expect(isDone).to.be.true;
      done();
   }, 5001);
});

// now with flush
it('should be done', function(){
   expect(isDone).to.be.false;
   $timeout.flush();
   expect(isDone).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've been playing with this, and I'm still having an issue. If I have one method in my controller that creates the timer, and another the stops the timer, an exception gets thrown. Why?

Comment: var myTimer = null;  $scope.hasStarted = false;
    $scope.start = function () {
        if ($scope.hasStarted === false) {
            $scope.isTimerActive = true;
            myTimer = $timeout(function () { $scope.isTimerActive = false; }, 5000);
            myTimer.catch(function (err) {
              alert("An error happened with the clock.");
            }); }}      $scope.stopClock = function () {
        $timeout.cancel(myTimer);
        $scope.isClockActive = false;
    }

Comment: I am confused, why did you post that code as a comment? What does it mean? Por que?

Comment: I updated the question to format code better. Essentially, I still don't understand the exception handling piece. Why would an exception get thrown if I try to cancel a timer that is running? Shouldn't it just get stopped?

Comment: It will be stopped. But lets say you wrote code that someone else is consuming. They may not know that the `promise` came from a timer. If that promise does not resolve it will `catch`, and an canceled timer will not resolve.